# Android TabLayout will not align right once Activity is resumed

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am using a TabLayout to navigate between fragments in my application. I would like the tabs to be aligned to the right of the Toolbar (next to the settings icon). And it does display like this when I first open the app:

[image: Desired Layout]

However, when I rotate the screen to landscape and then back to portrait, the tabs become centered in the Toolbar:

[image: Undesired Layout]

Here is the code for the Toolbar, in **activity_main.xml**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_white_24dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:paddingLeft="56dp"
                android:paddingStart="56dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
              android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabMaxWidth="56dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And the **onCreate** method of **MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    tv.setText(viewPager.getAdapter().getPageTitle(viewPager.getCurrentItem()));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            super.onTabSelected(tab);
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
            tv.setText(tabText[tab.getPosition()]);

        }
    });
}
```

**setupViewPager** method:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new HotFragment(), "Hot");
    adapter.addFragment(new YourPostsFragment(), "Your Posts");
    adapter.addFragment(new ExploreMapFragment(), "Explore");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**setupTabIcons** method:

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
    TabLayout.Tab hot = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
    TabLayout.Tab your_posts = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
    TabLayout.Tab explore = tabLayout.getTabAt(2);
    hot.setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    hot.setText(null);
    your_posts.setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    your_posts.setText(null);
    explore.setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    explore.setText(null);
}
```

I have tried many different XML properties, but I'm inclined to believe this is Java related, due to the problem occurring when the activity restarts. But I can't seem to find why this would happen. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I'm just curious, in `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`, you used `android:gravity="right"`, isn't that it suppose to be `android:layout_gravity="right"`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did when i had your problem:

1. started new project *(select tabbed activity)* with android studio (inspired by their code).
2. this is part of my xml

   ```
               <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
               ...>

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       ...            >

       <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
           android:id="@+id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:tabMode="fixed"
           android:layout_gravity="right"
           android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
           style="@style/AppTabLayout"/>

   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   ```

[And this is what i got:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ3EQ.png)
*edit margin right as you wish*